# ASP.NET Master Page not updating Child Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have made a site that is based off of a MasterPage and after creating a few pages I added a new `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` but it seems the existing pages wont update to include it, however new pages do.

Is there a way to force an update, or is there a proper way to do this? I just saved the Master Page and hoped for the best.

Comment: Did you set the existing content pages' `MasterPage` in the page directive?

Comment: It's the same `MasterPage` this is the code at the top linking it `<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="addons.aspx.vb" Inherits="basic_plan" %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the new `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` to your old `aspx` pages manually.

in your master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="new_one" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

in your old aspx pages, add:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="new_one" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Surely this is not the case, if my site where any bigger this would be almost unfeasable

Comment: This did work, but I still retain that there must be a better/dynamic way to do it automatically

Comment: @Joshua, when you create an content page from the master page, the HTML markup of the content page is created at that time. If you later added a new `<asp:Content>` in the master page, your old aspx pages won't be getting the updates. As far as I know, Visual Studio does not update it automatically.

Comment: Would this be the case if I decided to add a jQuery include at a later date? So if I add the `<script>` tags into the `MastePage` html will it need to be forced or would it come in its own?

Comment: @Joshua, regular html content won't cause this problem. only when you adding new asp:content tags. maybe you should take a look at nested master page and see if that fit your need better.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new content placeholder in your master page, your content pages don't NEED to have a corresponding `<asp:Content>`.  They only need one if you want to replace the default content placed in the master page.

And if you're going to update each page with its own content, then adding the `<asp:Content>` tags is likely a relatively small inconvenience.

Unfortunately there is not a way for Visual Studio to search out all your content pages and update them with new `<asp:Content>` controls.

However, you could do it fairly quickly by finding using the id of an existing `<asp:Content>` control, and do a `ctrl`+`shift`+`F` and replace with your new `<asp:Content>` plus what you searched for.

For example, if your content pages already all had a

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="old_one" ... />
```

then you could search for that and replace with

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="new_one" runat="server" /><asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="old_one" ... />
```

Not exactly pretty, but it could save some time.