# Using master pages in ASP.NET, how to do it efficiently to update child pages?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I started not long ago to develop my web pages using visual studio. I do not need to build a dynamic web site for now, but I'm used to the vs environment, so might as well.

My question is, if I create a master page at first, then a few child pages, vs could add the master page to those child pages easily with the correct content tags added in for you.

What if later I decide to change my master page and add a few more contentplaceholder which are have empty content in most of the child pages. Well according to this thread, the child pages will not automatically update with an empty content tag.

[ASP.NET Master Page not updating Child Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979196/asp-net-master-page-not-updating-child-page)

I was wondering how do the professionals use the the master pages efficiently. I mean do they also go into each of the child pages and manually add a content tag. What if there are lots and lots of child pages using that master page?

Perhaps the pros plan ahead and use many child master pages and web user controls to mitigate the problem. Perhaps they have another method. What would be a good plan?

Comment: If you have a master page with a content place holder, and the child 'sits' inside that content place holder - the child 'cares about' nothing else out side of that. If you were to add another content place holder to that master page elsewhere it would make no difference. This is fundamental to the flexibility that master pages offer you.

Comment: *face palm* Omg, my bad. I just tried what you said. I thought that if I added a new contentplaceholder in my master, it would break the child pages if I don't add a content tag. Well, now I just realized it runs just fine.

Comment: What do you mean a content tag? I think I'm a bit confused here. As long as it's working how you want it though.